# Firestore takes a long time to end execution after executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a really simple Firestore app. Besides the setting up with `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`, it's only this:

```
db.collection("users").add({
    username: username
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

Yet when I run this application with `node index.js`, it writes `Document written with ID:  XYZ` and then it takes an additional minute to end and give control back to the terminal. I might not be using the precise terms here, so a correction would be appreciated as well.

Is there a reason for this? Should I be terminating the connection or something?

Comment: You can put `process.exit()` inside the `.then()` handler.

Comment: It looks like Firestore has a `.terminate()` method to close all open streams.  There is also a `.waitForPendingWrites()` method that returns a promise and I don't know if you have to call that first (and wait for completion) befoire calling `.terminate()` or if `.terminate()` handles that for you.

Comment: Similar discussion here [Why is my nodejs script waiting 60 seconds before terminating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314387/why-is-my-node-script-waiting-60-seconds-to-terminate-after-a-cloud-firestore-qu), though it has a different recommendation than using `.terminate()`.  But apparently, there are some internal Firestore timers that cause the 60 second issue.  I'm not sure if that answer is better than using `.terminate()`.

Comment: So it's actually a firebase thing. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for a simple app, so it might not suit you.

**Promise version:**

If you want to keep the structure I presented in the question, then this is the final version

```
db.collection("users").add({
    username: "John"
})
.then( (docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch( (error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
})
.then( () => {
    console.log("Done");
    db.terminate();
})
```

**Async await version:**

But I'm not a fan of this whole `.then()` and `.catch()`, so I decided to convert it to an anonymous self-executing async function instead. You obviously don't need to make it self-executing or anonymous if you don't want to.

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const docRef = await db.collection("users").add({
            username: "John"
        });
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    } finally {
        console.log("Done");
        db.terminate();
    }
})();
```

In this specific use case it might not seem that simple, but using async await makes the function sequential and easier to read, I'm my opinion.